# Draw 7- dimentional space

Tags: vector, draw, dimension

I need to represent vectors in 7- dimensional space.
How can I draw them and plot points on them?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a reasonable way to draw something 7-dimensional. Best thing to do is to draw several projections in fewer dimensions for instance 2 or 3. Even 4 dimensions is hard to comprehend for men.

Comment: nope, it's pretty easy, I can imagine any 4-dimensional object in outstanding  clarity, it's just that no one believes me)))

Comment: "... hard to comprehend for men" - are you saying that women can visualise 4D better than men? That must be why I'm always late to dinner dates with my wife :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo no sexism implied I used men in the meaning of "people", not in the meaning of "male beings from the human species".

Comment: @shabunc i don't believe you :P